# Criteria API - multiselect - Tuple which contains other Tuple/Collection

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, multi-select, criteria-api

I have following entities:

```
class Person {
   int id;
   String name;
   List<Address> addresses
}

class Address {
  int id;
  String city;
}
```

I try to prepare query (based on Criteria-API) where result (each tuple  in result List) will contain three elements:

1. persron.id
2. person.name
3. person.addresses <-- collection with 0 or more elements

(1, "Peter", Collection{2,3}) or 
(1, "Peter", Tuple{2,3})

I have tried something like this:

```
EntityManager em;
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = qb.createTupleQuery()
Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);

ListJoin<PersonalData, Address> join = (ListJoin)root.join("addresses", JoinType.LEFT);

cq.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("name"), join.get("id"));

TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
List<Tuple> result = tq.getResultList();
```

But received result is different that expected :(

For model: Person(1, "Peter")

which has two addresses

Address(2, "London");
Address(3, "Paris");

my result list is something like Cartesian product:

(1, "Peter", 2), (1, "Peter", 3)

Is is possible to receive result which was requested at the beginning of this post?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can not work the way you are expecting, as the join between person and address will result in a single address per row, and JPA will return the data in a similar format.  One person.id, person.name, person.address in each tuple.   Why not just return the Person instance and use that?

Comment: My domain entities contain some logic which shouldn't be exposed for other system components. Therefore I try to generate something like dynamic DTO. Each component which want to know something about data model can call method which will return selected info about selected entity.

Comment: Seems like you have a perfectly good object model that could be reused for the purpose of representing your data instead of business logic specific to one purpose.  Regardless, though its not the answer you want, I don't think you will find a way with JPA queries to get collections of collections without returning entities.

Comment: It is clear that business model is not so good but I cannot change it. Application is huge and it is a reason why I try to separate model and components around this model. First idea which comes to my mind is just prepare DTOs at the top of my model. Seems that approach with using criteria API doesn't resolve my problem. I will try to use JPA queries. Thanks for your responses guys.